# PhpStorm not to generate docblock for function/method arguments that are typehinted

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, php-7, docblocks

At the moment on my PhpStorm I have the following options enabled:

```
File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | Missing @return tag` ->  Marked both options there (Ignore PHPDoc without @param + Ignore PHPDoc with return type hint).
File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHPDoc comment matches function/method signature` ->  Mark option about allowing params with typehint.
```

So according to these settings my functions should look like this:

```php
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function submit(string $email, string $message): Response
{ 
    throw new \Exception('whatever'); 
}
```

Never the less when I have a function with no docblock and I press on PhpStorm to auto generate the docblock for this function then it generates the docblocks also for the already typehinted arguments:

So a function like this:

```php
public function submit(string $email, string $message): Response
{ 
    throw new \Exception('whatever'); 
}
```

Will be converted to this:

```php
/**
 * @param string $email
 * @param string $message
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function submit(string $email, string $message): Response
{ 
    throw new \Exception('whatever'); 
}
```

Is there a way that I can configure my PhpStorm to generate the docblocks **ONLY** for parameters that do **NOT** have typehints.

Note that I know I can configure the templates from PhpStorm. I tried that solution.

On templates you can only tell PhpStorm it's all or nothing. I could not find a way of telling on templates to have the param docblocks only for those **WITHOUT** typehint.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38844 -- is my best match so far.