# Does PhpStorm allow to skip PHPDoc tags when type hints is declared?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting

I use PHP strict types `declare(strict_types=1);` and declare types through the project. Also I have enabled PHPDoc inspections in  PhpStorm such as `Argument PHPDoc missing`, `Missing @return tag` and others. 
I want PhpStorm not showing warnings regarding PHPDoc when I have explicit return type and parameter type declarations.

Here is valid the sample code in terms of PhpStorm.

```php
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws DBALException
     */
    public function find(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $user = $this->repository->find($request->get('id'));
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
        return $this->json($user);
    }
```

As we can see, I have explicit parameter type `Request $request` and return type `: JsonResponse` declarations, so there is no need to duplicate them in PHPDoc.

I want to exclude this lines from PHPDoc

```php
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
```

without warnings from PhpStorm, but only in case I have declared type hints. Nonetheless I want to see warnings when my code doesn't have type hints.

Is it possible to achieve? If no, does some JetBrains ticket exists or is there some plugins/tools to cover my case?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57347491/783119 . This is my best match so far: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38844

Comment: @LazyOne , thank you for clarification. It turned out PHPStorm has already this option. See my own answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Post answer by myself.

It turned out there are configuration options for PHP inspections (version of PHPStorm 2019.2):

- Ignore PHPDoc with return type hint (disabled by default)
- Allow missing parameters with type hints (disabled by default)

[image: Screenshot of Inspections configuration]

Comment: They seem to have taken this option out :( using `PhpStorm 2021.1.2`